# Umbraco webmatrix vs nuget

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

Is there any difference in functionality between installing umbraco via the webmatrix installer compared to installing the nuget package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the same install of Umbraco, so no there's no difference with regards to Umbraco. Of course there's a difference in the way you install it and maintain it. It's up to you to make a choice, whatever you're most comfortable with.

Note that when you do install through webmatrix it is then harder to work with Umbraco through Visual Studio (in case you prefer using VS).

Installation documentation available here: https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Install/